# Do bundles stack with every startActivity()?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, bundle

I have 3 activities, A, B, and C. If I pass an intent from A to B

```
//from A
Intent i1 = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
Bundle firstBundle = new Bundle();
firstBundle.putString("Key1", "Value1");
i1.putExtras(firstBundle);

//to B
Intent i1 = getIntent();
```

And if I add another bundle from B to C

```
//from B
Intent i2 = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
Bundle secondBundle = new Bundle();
secondBundle.putString("Key2", "Value2");
i2.putExtras(secondBundle);

//to C
Intent i2 = getIntent();
```

Would I be able to use this in C?

```
Intent i3 = getIntent();
Bundle thirdBundle = i3.getExtras();
String firstString = thirdBundle.getString("firstKey");
```

Can I get the items from `firstBundle` even though it is from a different intent? If not, how can I make it happen? Is it even efficient to do it this way? Is there a better way?

Comment: To access the first bundle data in C you may put all the data of firstBundle to secondBundle. You may simply do this using secondBundle.putAll(i1.getExtras())

Answer (score 0):

To get data from existing intent you need to call `getIntent().getExtras()` wich return current `Bundle`. You are creating `secondBundle` with new instance but you need to use `Bundle secondBundle = getIntent().getExtras();`